# How to run cron job using Quartz Scheduler framework in Java?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz Scheduler in Java to run cron jobs. This is the first time I am using this framework to run the cron jobs so I am having some confusion.

I was following this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/example-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-quartz/) to get the better understanding how to use Quartz framework.

I am trying to run `JobA` every week and every month so I started with basic example -

Here is my example which I have got so far.

```
public class JobA implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Job A is runing");

        // print whether it is week or month
    }
}
```

Below is my CronTriggerExample which schedules the job to run

```
public class CronTriggerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JobKey jobKeyA = new JobKey("jobA", "group1");
        JobDetail jobA = JobBuilder.newJob(JobA.class).withIdentity(jobKeyA)
                .build();

        Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("5 8 * * 6 ?"))
                .build();

        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobA, trigger1);
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

I am not sure how to run JobA every week and every month using the above code. What will be my cron tab entry for a week and month in my case? I don't want to run any Job between 8 PM till 5 AM and any random day is fine.

If JobA is running every week, then it should print out `one-week` and `report_week`. But if JobA is running every month, then it should print out `one-month` and `report_one_month` so the next question is - Is there any way, we can pass parameters to JobA when we try to run it?

Comment: You can parametrize your `Job` using a `JobDataMap`: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example4.html

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of the 7 fields of cron in quartz:

```
second minute hour day month week year
```

`year` field is optional. `*` means every, for example, `*` in `week` field means every week, so you should use `*` in both `week` field and `month` field. Note 
when the `week` field is specified, don't forget to use `?` in `day` field.

My example cron entry for you requirement is:

```
0 0 0 ? * *
```

which means running the job every week and every month on 00:00:00, please tune it for your need.

For more information, reference: [CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Note : To write your own Cron expression, take a look at http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Answer (score -1):

```
You can pass JobData if required

JobBuilder.newJob(JobClass.class);
jobDetail = jobBuilder.usingJobData("Key", "VALUE")
                    .withIdentity(dbname.getSchemaName(), "group1").build();


However for your case you need to modify cron expression provided in your cronschedular

http://www.cronmaker.com/

Follow above link to build cron expression
```